# For the function $Y = e^{-x}$ where $X$ is $N (0,1)$

Tags: probability

For the function $Y = e^{-X}$ where $X \sim N (0,1)$ show that the variance of $Y = e(e−1)$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: to show the variance is 
\begin{equation}
Y = e(e - 1)
\end{equation}
Sorry for the formatting earlier. quite new to mathJax

Comment: The variance should be given by
$$
\mathbf{Var}(Y)=\mathbf{E}(Y^2)-\mathbf{E}(Y)^2
$$
I am not sure how to get ${E}(Y^2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
\Bbb E\exp(aX) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(ay-y^2/2)
\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp (-(a-y)^2/2)\exp(a^2/2)
\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2\pi}} = \exp(a^2/2)
$$because the integral is the normalization of a variable $N(a,1)$.

details:

The variance you look for is then
$$
\exp(2^2/2) - \exp(1/2)^2 = e^2-e
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use change of variables technique and find the distribution of $Y$, then you'll be able to identify the distribution, and we'll be able to calculate the variance: Take a look at this: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157